# Failing to compile project using CUDA 11.0, Python 3.8, Torch 1.8

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pytorch, cuda

I am trying to compile [DiffDVR](https://github.com/shamanDevel/DiffDVR), a differentiable renderer. This requires running cmake first, so I had to install some dependencies. I want to use the same dependencies as the ones in the repo. I'm on Linux Mint 20.3, which is based on Ubuntu 20.04.
In order, I have installed:

- CUDA 11.0 (using the official [runfile](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=runfilelocal))
- cuDNN v8.1.1 (the highest version compatible with 11.0, as per the [cuDNN archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive))
- created a Python 3.8 environment with Torch 1.8.0 (based on the environment.yml file in the repo)
- libglm-dev, libglfw3-dev and libglew-dev as they were needed for compilation.

The error I get when going to the build dir and running `cmake ..` is:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
TORCH_LIB_c10
    linked by target "Renderer" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/renderer
    linked by target "Gui" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/gui
TORCH_LIB_c10_cuda
    linked by target "Renderer" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/renderer
    linked by target "Gui" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/gui
TORCH_LIB_torch_cpu
    linked by target "Renderer" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/renderer
    linked by target "Gui" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/gui
TORCH_LIB_torch_cuda
    linked by target "Renderer" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/renderer
    linked by target "Gui" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/gui
TORCH_LIB_torch_python
    linked by target "Renderer" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/renderer
    linked by target "Gui" in directory /home/andrei/PycharmProjects/DiffDVR/gui
```

Scrolling up in the output reveals the following problem:
`Torch: full library list: /usr/lib/libtorch.so;TORCH_LIB_c10-NOTFOUND;TORCH_LIB_c10_cuda-NOTFOUND;/usr/lib/libtorch.so;TORCH_LIB_torch_cpu-NOTFOUND;TORCH_LIB_torch_cuda-NOTFOUND;TORCH_LIB_torch_python-NOTFOUND`

So it seems like these libraries are not found. I tried to `sudo apt-get install libtorch3-dev` but apt says it's already installed (I assume it happened when conda installed the pytorch package?), and there are no libraries available with the c10, c10_cuda etc suffixes. How would I make sure these libraries are found, so I can compile the project?

---

I made some progress with the following (hacky) solution:

```sh
sudo ln -s /home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so libc10.so
sudo ln -s /home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so libc10_cuda.so
sudo ln -s /home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so libtorch_cpu.so
sudo ln -s /home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so libtorch_cuda.so
sudo ln -s /home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so libtorch_python.so
```

Which fixed the previous errors.

Unfortunately, I'm now encountering the following error:

```
CMake Error at renderer/CMakeLists.txt:92 (add_library):
  CUDA_STANDARD is set to invalid value '17'
```

---

More progress:
Managed to run cmake successfully by uninstalling it via apt and reinstalling it via snap (because the apt version was too old). Unfortunately, `make` fails now, with the error:

```
[ 46%] Building CXX object renderer/CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/volume.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/project/renderer/volume.cpp:1:
/opt/project/renderer/volume.h:9:10: fatal error: torch/types.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <torch/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [renderer/CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/build.make:76: renderer/CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/volume.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:244: renderer/CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Comment: The list of libraries is [defined via](https://github.com/shamanDevel/DiffDVR/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L101) `set(TORCH_LIBRARY_NAMES c10 c10_cuda torch torch_cpu torch_cuda torch_python)` and has a comment "# get libraries (hard coded), copied from torch.utils.cpp_extension.CUDAExtension". Not sure what this comment means, but similar libraries are noted in the [pytorch code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py#L931).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: specifying all the paths manually worked. In my case, this was:

```sh
cmake .. -DTORCH_PATH=/home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch -DTorch_DIR=/home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/lib/libpython3.8.so -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/andrei/miniconda3/envs/py38torch18/bin/python
```